# How to read XY, get raster value and then update field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I've written a script to run through a point layer, using the SearchCursor in the data access module and then read the XY values.  Within the `with` statement, I then use `GetCellValue` to get the elevation values and print them.

What I'd like to do is go one step further and write the value to a field in the row.  Is there a way to do this?  I can use `CalculateField`, but that'll be slow as it'll have to use a query to limit itself to the current row.  I can also possibly use a list to write the values to and then run through the list and update the fields using the `UpdateCursor`, but I think that'll be slow too.

Is there a way to do this inside the `with` statement?

```
import arcpy

##arcpy.AddField_management('C:\Data\Surveyed.shp', 'Z', 'DOUBLE')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('C:\Data\Surveyed.shp', ['SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        result = arcpy.GetCellValue_management('Database Connections\DC_SDEEBG_gisp.sde\SDEEBG.GIS.SRTM_DEM_NSWVICTAS_1SEC', str((row[0])[0]) + " " + str((row[0])[1]), "1")
        CellValue = float(result.getOutput(0))
        print CellValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you should use **[arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000)** instead of arcpy.da.SearchCursor.

### Elaboration:

This is what I would try:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.AddField_management('C:\Data\Surveyed.shp', 'Z', 'DOUBLE')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(r'C:\Data\Surveyed.shp', ('SHAPE@XY', 'Z')) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        result = arcpy.GetCellValue_management('Database Connections\DC_SDEEBG_gisp.sde\SDEEBG.GIS.SRTM_DEM_NSWVICTAS_1SEC', str((row[0])[0]) + " " + str((row[0])[1]), "1")
        CellValue = float(result.getOutput(0))
        print CellValue
        #  Use CellValue to set the second value (Z)
        row[1] = CellValue
        #Update the FC row
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?  I've been stuffing around with `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`, but I couldn't get it going.  Can you search and write rows with this?

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked a charm.  Had to make a small edit, but that was minor.  Much appreciated.